# Java : Passing null as Long in PreparedStatement (JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a variable which is

```
Long val = null;
```

And I am looking for a way to pass this to PreparedStatement statement object in order to set the field value in the database as null.

```
statement.setLong(1,val);
```

It does not work for Long, but only long.

Any inputs ideas, or suggestions.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use the [`setNull` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29).

```
statement.setNull(1, Types.BIGINT);  // Types.BIGINT maps to 64-bit long
```

When mapping Java types to JDBC types, [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) states:

> The recommended Java mapping for the BIGINT type is as a Java long.